# Convert nvarchar(255) to date SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, select

I need covert this:

```
Jan 18 2019 12:00AM
```

to this:

```
20190118
```

in SQL

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's good that you found an answer, but you will have a better experience here if you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then write your questions with the details needed to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of SQL Server's flexibility to recognize various date formats.

If you have the right regional settings, this should just work:

```
cast(mycol as date)
```

This gives you back a value of `date` datetype that corresponds to the input string;

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=260b8719ee239df963e0824205639d32)**:

```
select cast('Jan 18 2019 12:00AM' as date)
```

```
| (No column name) |
| :--------------- |
| 2019-01-18       |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT Format(Cast('Jan 18 2019 12AM' as date),'yyyyMMdd')
```

Read more about [Cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) functions in TSQL.

Comment: format is slow because it uses the dot.net framework.  use convert instead

Answer (score 0):

use convert (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp)

```
SELECT Convert(varchar(30),Cast('Jan 18 2019 12AM' as date),101)
```

output:

```
01/18/2019
```